# CodeIgniter Template variables not working all the time

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter

I'm trying to allow each of my pages to have a dynamic title field.

I'm using [this template system](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template) library with CodeIgniter 2.

Below is a sample of my opening tags, showing that I'm using a variable called `$title` to store the current page's title.

```
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>CnCFPS <?php echo "| $title"; ?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
        <meta name="Description" content="Todo" />
        <meta name="Keywords" content="Todo" />
```

I'm writing it out to the view using `$this->template->write_view( 'content', 'path/to/view', $data' );` in which `$data` is an array:

```
$data['recaptcha']          =   $this->recaptcha->get_html();
$data['title']              =   "Account Registration";
```

`$title` seems to not exist on the template as a variable because all I get is "CnCFPS | " between the `<title>` tags. The `$recaptcha` variable works perfectly fine though.

I've attempted the example on [the link above](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template) using `$this->template->write( 'title', 'Insert Title Here');` and even defined a title in my $template array from `configs\template.php`.

**I don't know what's up with this and why it won't display the page title.**

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it's getting set to null or something. Can you run some code to see if it is indeed empty ( empty($title) ? 'yes' : 'no')? Also try changing the name from $data['title'] to $data['foo'] or something.

Comment: What does var_dump($data) return?

Comment: @Fox: Nothing outputs (weird, yes)
@starsinmypockets: Where should I put that? In the view or in the caller of the view?

Comment: I put `if ( $region == 'content' ) show_error( print_r( $data, true ) );` in CI_Template::write_view right above where it calls the native CI method to load the view, and `$data['title']` is set... :\ It just doesn't seem to like my variables :(

Comment: Ok so those debug lines I just put in...I undid them and now it works... >.<

Comment: Sounds like you had something weird in your code. I've had to just rewrite my code to fix bugs before. Glad it's working!

Comment: If this issue is resolved please either answer your question and mark it answered or delete it. Thank you :-D

Answer (score 0):

a few things to try.

instead of using `$data['title'] use $this->data['title']` and call `$data['title']` for the title instead of $title.

you'll have to change all $data arrays in the function to be `$this->data[]`.

And the other thing, stupid but escape out your variable. Its best practice.

`<title>CnCFPS<?php echo " | ".$title; ?></title>`